# Restart camunda process from cockpit

Tags: camunda

I want to modify some variable in my running process and then restart the instance.

in this example i want ot increment maxRetry :

[image]

When i pause and start the process, nothing happens.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean by restart the instance? Start it again from the start event? Your process is waiting on the event gateway. Are the messages really produced? I'm trying to figure out what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hello,
I mean when my process instance is locked, and i correct it's variables, who can i replay it

Comment: But what do you want to replay? The process instance in the picture is waiting for an event. You said pause and start the process. Do you mean suspend and activate?

Comment: that's exactelly what i meant,i want to suspuend the process and reactivate it

Comment: But it's waiting for an event and as long as it doesn't receive it, it won't move anywhere. If you want to start from different activity, you'll need to use process instance modification api. https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.9/user-guide/process-engine/process-instance-modification/